# Boost generated successfully but can't generate a makefile. Where did I go wrong?

Tags: boost, cygwin, cmake, cross-compiling

Even though CMake has successfully configured and generated the makefile with Boost, I just can't produce an executable file for ARM processor using the make command as shown below.

[image]

Here is my configuration setting:

1.) I downloaded boost library 1.49 compiled in Raspberry Pi in this link:
http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=8111&p=195468

2.) The file hierarchy is as follows:

```
sample-boost
   -> boost-stage (Contains the lib, and include directories of the boost taken from number 1)
   -> build (Contains the generated files from CMake)
   -> CMakeLists.txt
   -> main.cpp
```

NOTE: The ARM Cross Compiler is fully working and I've cross compiled a hello world and run it in Raspberry Pi successfully using CMake in Cygwin (using a cross toolchain file located in C:/cygwin/arm-pi.toolchain.cmake).

3. main.cpp

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <boost/thread.hpp>

   int main(){

   cout << "Hello" << endl;
   boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::millisec(20));
   return 0;
   }
   ```
4. CMakeLists.txt

   ```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
   Project(main)
   SET(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR C:/Users/Emmett/Documents/EMMETT/sample-boost/boost-stage/include)
   SET(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH ${CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH} "C:/Users/Emmett/Documents/EMMETT/sample-boost/boost-stage/include")
   SET(BOOST_ROOT C:/Users/Emmett/Documents/EMMETT/sample-boost/boost-stage)

   FIND_PACKAGE(Boost)

   message("BOOST LIBRARY" ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
   message("Boost LIBRARIES:" ${Boost_LIBRARIES})


   IF(Boost_FOUND)  
   message("Boost include directory is found")
   message("Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS": ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
   include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
   add_executable(main main.cpp)
   target_link_libraries( main ${Boost_LIBRARIES} )
   ENDIF(Boost_FOUND)
   ```
5. Boost-stage
    -> include (came from sample-boost\boost_1_49_0\boost)

[image]

```
  -> lib (came from boost_1_49_0(bin-only)\lib
```

[image]

Also, invoking ccmake . shows that boost_dir is not found. However, boost package is found!

[image]

As you can see, it has successfully generated makefiles using CMake but I can't create an executable file for it. I think I missed out something in setting up boost. Maybe I've failed to successfully link the libraries? Does not the

```
    message("Boost LIBRARIES:" ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

display the library files?

ADDITION: I did what you ask for. Here is my new cmakelists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
Project(main)
SET(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR C:/Users/Emmett/Documents/EMMETT/sample-boost/boost-stage/include)
SET(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH ${CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH} "C:/Users/Emmett/Documents/EMMETT/sample-boost/boost-stage/include")
SET(BOOST_ROOT C:/Users/Emmett/Documents/EMMETT/sample-boost/boost-stage)
SET(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS TRUE)
SET(Boost_DEBUG ON)
#FIND_PACKAGE(Boost)
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost COMPONENTS thread)

message("BOOST LIBRARY: " ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
message("Boost LIBRARIES: " ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
message("LIBS : " ${LIBS})

IF(Boost_FOUND)
    message("Boost include directory is found")
    message("Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS: "${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    add_executable(main main.cpp)
    target_link_libraries( main ${Boost_LIBRARIES} )
ENDIF(Boost_FOUND)
```

Here is the output console:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For using the boost thread module with CMake you must do

```
find(Boost COMPONENTS thread)
```

Normaly, this add the path to the boost thread lib in `Boost_LIBRARIES` var.

Comment: I replaced find_package(Boost) by find_package(Boost COMPONENTS thread). It said that it cannot find boost anymore.

Comment: You can set `Boost_DEBUG` to ON to enable debug output from FindBoost.

Comment: I did what you ask. I really don't know what the problem is. It seems that it was able to scan the boost thread libs and still reports that Boost was not found and no boost libraries were found. Also, I don't know the effect of enabling the use_static_libs

Comment: See http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#module:FindBoost for have help on findBoost. I think youy must use `BOOST_INCLUDEDIR`, `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR` and `Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS` var.

Comment: If a library was found, library files will be listed when Boost_LIBRARIES var is being displayed? Also, are there no debug and release libraries in Linux?